# Unity - get component during build process

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to access the variables of a script attached to a GameObject during the build process using the IPostprocessBuildWithReport-Interface?

The following returns a NullReferenceException:

```
MyScript script = GameObject.Find("MyGO").GetComponent<MyScript>();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with a singleton instance, don't use Gameobject.find